# Zabbix user parameter doesn't work

Tags: zabbix

I created this UserParameter on a RedHat 6.6 server. This server is a Zabbix 2.4 client.

```
UserParameter=replication_status,mysql -se "show slave status\G" | grep Seconds_Behind_Master: | awk '{print $2}'
```

I created a Item with this key "replication_status" and a graph with this Item. If I run this command in terminal

```
mysql -se "show slave status\G" | grep Seconds_Behind_Master: | awk '{print $2}'
```

I receive 0, wich is normal but the graph say [no data]
How can I debug this problem? I have others parameter and graphs that work s fine but this one doesn't.

Comment: As which user do you execute it in the terminal? What's in the logs of the agent as well as the server?

Answer (score 1):

> To use positional references unaltered, specify double dollar sign -
>   for example, awk '{print $$2}'. In this case $$2 will actually turn
>   into $2 when executing the command.

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/userparameters

OK, this is not your problem, see comment from @asaveljevs

Comment: This does not seem to be apparent from the documentation (we shall improve!), but double dollar sign is only a solution for user parameters that accept arguments. In the question, a user parameter without arguments is used, so $$2 will be passed verbatim as $$2.

Comment: Documentation improvement request registered as [ZBX-10101](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-10101).